# How to Upload a Site (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting

I'm trying to upload my c# site,

The sites seems to upload correctly,

But when I try to enter, I get the next message:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now I add the customErrors mode="Off" to my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And the new error is:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.**

Source Error:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: \blablablablablabla\public_html\myweb\web.config    Line: 8

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8793; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8762

I tryed modifying it to 2.0 (because the error signature), also tryed to delete the targetFramework attribute, but nothing works.

Thaaaaanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS,
Click on Application Pool--> on the right side --> Select your Site--> double click on it and change the .Net Framework to v4.0

I hope it will solve your problem.
Thnks.

Comment: The only options in my webhosting are 2.0, 3.5, 4.7,

Comment: Should I install 4.7 in my pc? Or maybe just choose 4.7 on the web and being newer than my 4.0 is enough? Thanks.

Comment: Lets choose 4.7, and see what happen may be it helps you.